# How to solve a subprocess that contains a '|'

Tags: python, subprocess

This code does not work.
I wrote like this.

```
str = "curl -s 'URL_ADDRESS' | tail -1".split()
p = subprocess.Popen(str,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
data = p.read()
p.close()
print(data)
```

But the result is `b''`.
What's the problem with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use subprocess, use instead of '|' like this.

This will solve the problem.

```
str = "curl -s 'URL_ADDRESS'".split()

tail = "tail -1".split()

temp = subprocess.Popen(str, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout

temp1 = subprocess.Popen(tail, stdin=temp, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout

temp.close()

data = temp1.read()

temp1.close()
```